# Xcode not showing commits in Repository

Tags: xcode, git

So, I made a few commits today, but they are not showing in the Xcode Repository.

The curious thing is that the version of the project changes after every commit, but it just shows yesterday's commit.

I made a test commit showing the progress.

**Image 1** - Repository before commit

**Image 2** - commiting

**Image 3** - Repository after committing. (you can see the changed version of the project, but not on the repository.)

I have no idea what changed from yesterday.

Thanks in advance.

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

[image: Image 3]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a detached head, so your commits do not get onto `main`. To commit to `main`, first you need to *be* on `main`.

Comment: I appreciate your time, but have no idea what detached head means. Looking into it right now!

Comment: It means that at some earlier time you checked out a commit rather than a branch. All your commits since then have gone into empty space. One more good reason to use the command line; it would have shouted "be careful" at you. Xcode hides the reality.

Comment: Thank you. You pointed me into the right direction to solve it!